# MIDP application, blocked by Connector.Open(..)

Tags: java, multithreading, monitor, midp

I've been having the worst time of my life trying to understand why this is happening, any input would be greatly appreciated.

The code in question runs in a diffrent thread then the midlet, although the thread starts after the connection is made, I've tried the other way around and I end up at the same spot.

When executing this line (with a proven and working server address of course):

```
this.socket = (SocketConnection) Connector.open(url);
```

nothing happens and when I hit pause in debug it takes me to this msg:

```
@exception IllegalMonitorStateException if the current thread is not
the owner of the object's monitor.
```

Comment: it takes you to the javadoc? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Actually it takes me to the documentation above the wait method, I actually managed to get this semi working, I learned that if I start the connection during the startApp midlet function then it's fine, otherwise it still blocks, this doesntt make much sense either, unless there is a rule saying that a midp app can only connect on startup which i'm not aware of which would explain this...

Comment: I suggest that you tell us more about what phone/emulator you are running and that you post some of the code around the line you posted so far. Are you 100% sure you know how a Java monitor works?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement your socket and network code/modules in a seperate thread.